# How to handle PUT or POST without required (OAuth) Authorization header in a Rest Service

Tags: rest, post, oauth, authorization, put

I have trouble finding an answer to how a rest resource should respond to a client when an (OAuth) authorization header is missing (or invalid). For a GET request a redirect could be used, but in case of a POST or PUT this is not desirable.

What I would like to achieve is that a rest resource tells a client that it needs to get authorization. Preferably given the proper OAuth instructions (location of service, token type etc).

Answer (score 0):

If your rest resource complies with [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) (Bearer Token Usage), an error response should look like the following (an excerpt from [3. The WWW-Authenticate Response Header Field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-3)):

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="example"
```

Otherwise, if your rest resource does not comply with RFC 6750, you yourself should define your own response format. RFC 6750 is just a recommendation and you don't have to follow the specification if you don't like it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This makes some sense. But how does a client know where to get a Bearer token. The beauty of a redirect is that a client can be unaware of where and how to get a token.